# Sorting a dataframe by a column

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

Hi I need to sort a data frame. My data frame looks like below.

```
A   B
2   5
3   9
2   7
```

I want to sort this by column A.

```
A   B
2   5
2   7
3   9
```

when having duplicates in the column A,

```
sorted_data=data.sort_values(by=['A'], inplace=True)
```

doesn't workout. Any suggestion how I can fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has worked correctly. The problem is that if you use `inplace=True` the sorting is done in your original DataFrame, `data` in your case.

If you want the order dataframe and to store it in `sorted_data`, do the following:

```
sorted_data=data.sort_values(by=['A'])
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,2], 'B': [5,9,7]})
>>> df.sort_values(by=['A'],inplace=True)
>>> df
   a  b
0  2  5
2  2  7
1  3  9
```

The other way:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,2], 'B': [5,9,7]})
>>> sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=['A'])
>>> sorted_df 
   a  b
0  2  5
2  2  7
1  3  9
>>> df
   a  b
0  2  5
1  3  9
2  2  7
```

Comment: @user3789200 if you think the answer is correct, you can select is the right one. Thanks!